# How to let the app login automactically without opening the web?

Tags: android

I'm planning to make an application that can let the user accessing the Internet without opening the browser and type the login information to get the permission but just one click. I have no idea how to let the application open a web and fill the information without using a browser. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Depends what kind of login did you have in mind. Who is your login provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the login page of the website and examine the login form. Then use the DefaultHttpClient to send a Post request for the login.

This is roughly how I am using it:

```
public Boolean login() throws Exception {

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // add login data (edit this to fit your website)
    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NAME_OF_USERNAME_FIELD", USERNAME));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NAME_OF_PASSWORD_FIELD", PASSWORD));

    // create the request
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URL);
    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, DEFAULT_ENCODING));

    // execute the form
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpost);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
            .getContent(), DEFAULT_ENCODING));

    // fetch the result of the http request and save it as a string
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    String input = sb.toString();

    // check if the login worked. This depends on the response of your website
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(LOGIN_WORKED_PATTERN);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

    if (m.find())
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Adjust the code to fit your needs.

Comment: The result of the http request is the first page that used to fill the login form. How to get the page after submit?

Comment: I don't know, if I understand you correctly. After the request is sent, I indeed catch the response (see the comments in the code) and in the two lines after the last comment I check for the site to show the correct code, to determine if the login worked. This is some sort of parsing, if you want.

Comment: but it didn't post and I still got the form instead of the next page